# Need Help In Subquery/Join SQL

Tags: sql

I came across this exercise :

The following tables form part of a database held in a relational DBMS:

- hotel (**hotelNo**, hotelName, hotelAddress)
- room (**roomNo**, **hotelNo**, type, price)
- booking (**hotelNo**, **guestNo**, **dateFrom**, dateTo, roomNo)
- guest (**guestNo**, guestName, guestAddress)

Tasks:

1. List the price and type of all rooms at the “Green Palace” Hotel.
2. List all guests currently staying at the “Green Palace” Hotel.
3. List the details of all rooms at the “Green Palace” Hotel, including the name of the guest staying in the room, if the room is occupied.
4. What is the total income from bookings for the “Green Palace” Hotel today?
5. List the rooms that are currently unoccupied at the “Green Palace” Hotel.
6. What is the lost income from unoccupied rooms at the “Green Palace” Hotel?

The exercise states that I should use the subquery or join method.

I was able to answer the first question only

```
SELECT price, type
FROM room
WHERE hotelNo = (SELECT hotelNo
                 FROM hotel
                 WHERE hotelName = "Green Palace")
```

The other questions involved multiple subqueries in one statement (which I don't know how to do it), and I am not understanding the difference between subquery and join.
How can I answer the other questions?

Comment: I think you must use JOIN not Sub-Queries. 
So try: 
SELECT price, type
FROM room r JOIN hotel h on h.hotelNo = r.hotelNo
WHERE h.hotelName = "Green Palace"

Comment: Hello you are probably an NDU student taking CSC 226 if that is the case i found the exercise and its solution where the Dr probably got it from. https://www.javaguicodexample.com/mysqldatabasequerynetbeansex.html dont forget to change the hotel name. :)

Answer (score 0):

The approach with a **JOIN** for your first question could be something like this:

```
SELECT r.price, r.type
FROM room r
INNER JOIN hotel h ON r.hotelNo = h.hotelNo
WHERE h.hotelName = "Green Palace"
```

So instead of using a subquery to determine the relevant `hotelNo` (as you showed in your question), you're just joining (or "linking") the two involved tables, based on a common column, and using a `WHERE` clause to limit the hotels that you're looking at.

For question #2 - try something like this:

```
SELECT g.guestName, g.guestAddress
FROM guest g
INNER JOIN booking b ON b.guestNo = g.guestNo
INNER JOIN hotel h ON b.hotelNo = h.hotelNo
WHERE h.hotelName = 'Green Palace'
```

Join the guest with the bookings to find the guest's bookings, and then join the booking to the hotel table to limit your results to the bookings (of that particular guest) at the 'Green Palace' hotel.

This should hopefully give you a bit of a push - now try tasks #3 through #6 - and come back if you're stuck somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

A subquery is a request inside a request. You use it when you want to add a condition from another table which has few link with the current one.

```
select * from user where userId in (select id from person where name = 'plop')
```

A join is a relationship between two tables. If two tables are linked by a column (a foreign key), you will use joins (left or inner mostly). Your request will look like you have only one table containing all the datas from both tables.

```
select u.* from user u
inner join person p on u.userId = p.id
where p.name = 'plop'
```

With my examples, you will have the same results if User.userId is non nullable. If it is nullable, you will get the users who have userId = null too.

So for your first question, I would prefere using a join :

```
select r.price, r.type from room r
inner join hotel h on h.hotelNo = r.hotelNo
where h.hotelName = 'Green Palace'
```

The result will be the same but it is more readable and the execution plan will be less lost I guess.

Now, I won't do the whole exercice but I hope my answer will help you